# How to start an admin application while checking for another without UAC

Tags: batch-file

I've been messing with batch files, trying to start a program (specifically, a modded Skyrim game), but only start it if the application Steam is open. I got that far, and it works flawlessly. However, every time I do that, it asks me for UAC permission. I don't mind the UAC in general, and I'd prefer to keep it on, so I planned to just disable it for this application.

This is what I currently have in my .bat file
(yes, I do know it's messy, I'm just beginning this kind of stuff and I found most of the code somewhere else and suited it to what worked for me)

```
@echo off
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Steam.exe" | find /i "Steam.exe" >nul && (
elevate "C:\program files (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim\skse_loader.exe"
) || (
echo Steam
)
::pause>nul
```

Note that this makes use of the [Elevate](http://www.winability.com/elevate/) tool.

Now, this works perfectly to start Skyrim only if Steam is open. To get rid of the UAC prompt, I followed [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html) guide and adapted it to my situation.

```
@echo off
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Steam.exe" | find /i "Steam.exe" >nul && (
elevate C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "Skyrim"
) || (
echo Steam
)
::pause>nul
```

Which still only starts Skyrim, but it asks me if I want to allow the computer to "manage scheduled tasks" as a UAC prompt. I figured this was because I used "elevate" rather than "run". However, changing it to run makes nothing happen at all.

Sorry for the long question, but I wanted to give you a clear idea on what's going on! Thanks for any help you can offer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without `elevate` like the guide show you?

```
@echo off
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Steam.exe" | find /i "Steam.exe" >nul && (
  schtasks.exe /run /tn "Skyrim"
) || ( echo Steam )
::pause>nul
```